# php directory iterator list aplhabetically

Tags: php, iterator, directory-structure

For a project we have created a recursive direcory iterator inside a class

the class is as follows

```
class Helpers {

    public static function fs_to_array($directory){
        $iritator = new \RecursiveIteratorIterator(new \RecursiveDirectoryIterator($directory), \RecursiveIteratorIterator::CHILD_FIRST); 
        $array_result = array(); 

        foreach ($iritator as $splFileInfo) {
            $fn = $splFileInfo->getFilename();

            if ($splFileInfo->isDir()){  
                if ($fn == '..' || $fn == '.' ){
                    continue;
                }
                $rec_path = array($fn => array());
            }else{
                continue;
            }

            for ($depth = $iritator->getDepth() - 1; $depth >= 0; $depth--) { 
                $rec_path = array($iritator->getSubIterator($depth)->current()->getFilename() => $rec_path); 
            } 
            $array_result = array_merge_recursive($array_result, $rec_path);
        }
        return $array_result;
    }
}
```

it takes a directory as an argument and returns the dir structure in the following form

```
Array
(
    [dir3] => Array
        (
            [dir_in_dir3] => Array
                (
                )

        )

    [dir1] => Array
        (
            [dir_in_dir1] => Array
                (
                )

        )

    [dir2] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

I would like these to be allphavetically sorted.

How Can i make this with the iterator?

Thanks everybody  in advance!

Answer (score 0):

An iterator can't be sorted directly and the directory iterators also have not support for sorting of the underlying data. But you can convert the RecursiveIteratorIterator to an array with `iterator_to_array()` and then sort the array with `usort()` and a custom callback function using `getPathName()` on the elements. You could also use a `CallbackFilterIterator()` before the conversion to reduce the size of your array.

EDIT example:

```
$directory = '...';

$it = new CallbackFilterIterator(
        new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
            new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($directory), RecursiveIteratorIterator::CHILD_FIRST
        ), function ($entry) {
            // filtering unwanted elements to keep array small
            $fn = $entry->getFilename();
            if (!$entry->isDir()) {
                return false;
            } else if ($fn == '..' || $fn == '.') {
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        }
);

$array = iterator_to_array($it);
// sorting entries
uasort($array, function ($a, $b) {
    return strcmp($a->getPathname(), $b->getPathname());
});

// do whatever you want - can be uses just like the RecursiveIteratorIterator before
foreach ($array as $v) {
    var_dump($v->getPathname());
}
```

Comment: I am really sorry, I didnot understand you exactly... Could you point me to the right direction with a snippet maybe? thanks!